# normal distribution, mean=$20$, sd=$2$ , p$(x^2-x<2)$?

Tags: probability

normal distribution, mean=$20$, sd=$2$ , p$(x^2-x<2)$ I don`t know how to convert it to z-score form. i think if we put 2 on left side we get the p((x-2)(x+1)<0) form. but i don`t know how to get any further?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$(x-2)(x+1)<0\iff -1<x<2$